# How to get rid of highlighted errors in vs studio Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.43
I was doing some Python and I noticed that I usually would get red syntax error highlights, yellow highlights, etc. 
This really annoys me and I wanted to know if there is a way to get rid of it.[image: Description]

Comment: Check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer to this if anyone is wondering
This is because you have likely installed the following extension
[image: Description]
This is what is causing your lines to be highlighted so uninstall it and reload vs studio
And Ta-Da! No more annoying highlighting!